# Using PHP Variables as HTML Form Input Attributes

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to use PHP variables as attributes in form inputs?

I have the following variable already declared:

$InStock //number of items in stock

I would like to use this variable per below, but the code isn't working (the max constraint is not being applied to the field):

```
print "<td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='<?php echo $InStock ?>' value='0'></td>";
```

Is this legal, or am I attempting something syntactically impossible?  Sorry if this is a stupid question - I'm new at this, and I embarrass myself frequently.  : /

Comment: Change to : print "<td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='$InStock'...
Read some articles about quotes vs double-quotes, ex: http://www.scriptingok.com/tutorial/Single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-PHP

Comment: Thank you, @KA_lin - it was a stupid question, clearly.  Thanks for the reading material, and the patience to answer my question!  :)

Comment: You are very welcome, keep up the work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, your syntax is incorrect though. You're double dipping on the php brackets.

I usually prefer to do something like this instead of using print, it's easier to read, especially if your IDE is doing syntax highlighting:

```
?><td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='<?php echo $InStock ?>' value='0'></td><?php
```

You could also do it within a print/echo statement, but you need to have the variable inline without the extra brackets:

```
echo "<td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='$InStock' value='0'></td>";
```

Note that without concatenation, this only works with double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to the question - I clearly need to brush up on my syntax basics!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your:

```
print "<td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='<?php echo $InStock ?>' value='0'></td>";
```

Use:

```
print "<td><input type='number' name='product1' id='product1' min='0' max='$InStock' value='0'></td>";
```

This is because PHP will insert the values of variables into a string if you put the variable name into the string and PHP will replace this with the value of your variable. For example `print "Hi there, $name"`could produce `"Hi there, James"` when executed - assuming `$name` is equal to "James".

Please check this Muddal: http://muddal.com/muddaltut.php?id=163

Comment: Thanks, Xanco - I appreciate you taking the time to respond!  :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found your answer :)